# se puede obtener informacion con javascript de un xml cargado en input antes de pasarlo al lenguaje php?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

se puede obtener informacion con javascript de un xml cargado en input antes de pasarlo al lenguaje php? y si se puede como se ria la manera de hacerlo?
lo que quiero es extraer los UUID de los xml y dependiendo de los uuid mandar las variables a php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero cread tu input type file, luego obtienes el texto mediante el `FileReader` y luego lo muestras, te dejo un ejemplo

```js
var fileChooser = document.getElementById('fileChooser');

function parseTextAsXml(text) {
    var parser = new DOMParser(),
        xmlDom = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");

    //ahora, extraer los elementos del xmlDom y asignarlos a los imputs
}

function waitForTextReadComplete(reader) {
    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
        var text = event.target.result;

        parseTextAsXml(text);
    }
}

function handleFileSelection() {
    var file = fileChooser.files[0],
        reader = new FileReader();

    waitForTextReadComplete(reader);
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

fileChooser.addEventListener('change', handleFileSelection, false);
```

```html
<input id="fileChooser" type="file">
```

Comment: gracias amigo me sirvio de mucha ayuda tu script, mil gracias

Comment: amigo tome tu codigo para sacar el UUID de los xml cargados en el formulario y en esta funcion parseTextAsXml(text) retorno esta linea                return xmlDom.children[0].lastElementChild.children[0].attributes[3].nodeValue;
que es la que me regresa el uuid, mi pregunta es, como retorno la respuesta que me da esta funcion? waitForTextReadComplete(reader) que dentro de ella tiene otra funcion reader.onloadend = function(event)

Comment: FileReader.onloadend  es asincrono, por tal motivo, no devuelve datos. coloca la lógica en otra funcion y llámala cuando los datos esten cargados.

Comment: ya lo intente de muchas maneras amigo y no logro retornar el resultado de esta funcion handleFileSelection(), que a su vez tiene otra funcion reader.onloadend = function(event), no logro tener exito